# Devolver resultado de una llamada ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy haciendo una llamada por ajax para obtener un json para luego añadirlos a los eventos del calendario. Pero no se como hacerle llegar esa información.

```
$('#centros').on('change', function() {

    document.getElementById('calendar').innerHTML = "";
    calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');
    console.log(resul);
    //$idcentro = this.value;
    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, 
        {
            plugins: ['dayGrid', 'interaction', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
            header:{
                left:'prev,next,today',
                center:'title',
                right:''
            },
            firstDay: 1,
            eventClick:function(info){
                var months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
                var days   = ["0","01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"];
            },
            events:obtenerEventos(this.value),
            dayRender:function(info){
                if(info.date.getDay() == "0" || info.date.getDay() == "6")
                {
                    info.el.style.background="#aacc6163";
                }
                // info.el.innerHTML='<input></input><input></input>';
            }
        }
    );

    calendar.setOption('locale','Es');
    calendar.render();

});
```

Donde genere el calendario en la parte de eventos es donde tiene que recibir un json con los eventos

```
function obtenerEventos(id){
    $id = id;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' =>'CalendarioPlantillas', 'action' => 'eventosGerencia')); ?>", 
        headers : {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()
        },
        data:{
            idcentro:$id
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr) 
        {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        },
        success:function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            result = msg;
            return msg;
            //callback(msg);
        },
        error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorMessage){
            //alert("Ha ocurrido un error inesperado intentelo de nuevo");
            console.log(errorMessage);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

Y esta es la que me devuelve el json pero no se como pasarle la información ya que me devuelve undefined, se que es porque se ejecuta antes, pero no habría alguna manera de almacenarlo para luego pasarlo.

Comment: En `success`, en vez de retornar la variable, llama al método de _calendar_ donde llenas los días.

Comment: Hola, he organizado un poco tu código, tenias errores en el código, tal como un punto y coma donde no debía ir y unas comillas simples mal usadas que hacian un caos con PHP, tambien una función no cerrada, recuerda que no puedes poner el mismo tipo de comillas encerradas dentro de las mismas sin que desastres naturales ocurran, por cierto me gustaria preguntar una cosa... realmente obtienes de manera correcta el JSON en la parte del success a la hora de usar tu código así como esta??, porque tal cuál esta se supone que AJAX debería fallar...

Answer (score 1):

Pude ver ciertos errores ya mencionados en tu código, sin embargo omitiendo esos errores dices que obtienes un `JSON` aún así, por lo que omitamos esto y concentremonos en el resultado.

Recordemos algo, **AJAX es asincrono**, esto significa que tardará un tiempo en devolverte una respuesta o un error, como bien sabemos **javascript corre sobre un solo hilo siempre**, y no, no hay manera de que corra en varios hilos, la naturaleza de `javascript` es ser `monohilo`.

Esto significa que cualquier cosa que sea detectada como asincrona `SI` se ejecutara, pero javascript lo que hará es hacer que se ejecute y mientras obtiene una respuesta seguira ejecutando el código que se encuentra **DESPUES** de la llamada a `AJAX`.

Es decir, `javascript` no va a esperar a que `AJAX` devuelva un valor, simplemente deja que se ejecute y sigue ejecutando el resto.

Esto no pasa para operaciones que sean sincronas.

Sabiendo esto es normal toparnos conque al intentar recuperar la propiedad `events` de tu objeto sea `undefined` puesto que significa que `AJAX` aún no ha devuelto una respuesta.

**¿Entonces como logramos pasarle al objeto el valor obtenido por AJAX?**

Bueno... decir de primeras que lo que tenias en tu código original no era una función, era un objeto, por lo cual al ser un objeto no podemos hacer uso de `async - await` de manera directa dentro de el.

tambien estas teniendo una falla técnica a la hora de intentar 'devolver' la respuesta de `AJAX` puesto que aunque `AJAX` complete su respuesta, enrealidad nunca la estas devolviendo hacia afuera, te explico el porque:

```
$.ajax({});
```

Eso es una llamada a `AJAX` en su mas mínima expresión, en esta expresión, aunque sea una llamada inútil, lo podemos ver claramente, lo que le pasamos a `AJAX` es un `objeto`, viendo tu ejemplo tu tienes como una de las propiedades de este objeto la propiedad `success`, lo cual es normal:

```
success:function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
    result = msg;
    return msg;
    //callback(msg);
}
```

Pero ten en cuenta que en `JS` tenemos esto llamado `scope` o `bloque` el cuál se refiere a cualquier espacio delimitado entre llaves `{}` (literalmente cualquiera), por lo cual cuando haces `return` no estas retornando hacia la función `obtenerEventos`, estas retornando hacia la función `success`, que como sabrás no tiene sentido.

Así que te propongo algo, promisificar `AJAX`, puesto que intentes lo que intentes, hagas lo que hagas, **no debes** o por lo menos **no deberias** cambiar la naturaleza de `AJAX` de ser `asincrona` a pasar a ser `sincrona`, puesto que si lo haces se pueden generar varios tipos de errores indeseados.

Así que diré una cosa que te van a entristecer un poco, pero es para el bien de nosotros los programadores (y esto no es por conveniencia, si no porque sencillamente no hay mas opciones):

- No hay forma de usar directamente el valor de retorno de una función asincrona, puesto que éstas siempre hagas lo que hagas retornaran algo llamado `Promise`.

Para obtener los valores que contiene una `Promise`, solo hay dos opciones, una se limita a tener que usar una función asíncrona para poder usar la palabra reservada `await` y forzar con ello a que el código espere a que se `resuelva` o `rechace` la promesa (que nos devuelva ya sea el valor o un error), de esta manera simulamos hacer que `AJAX` sea sincrono.

Sin embargo como lo que tienes se trata de un objeto y no de una función esta opción no sería la mas adecuada... la otra opción reside en simplemente en vez de usar el valor directamente, devolver la `Promise` entera (ya que contiene los datos) y usar `.then` y `.catch` de la `promise` para poder usar su valor donde requieras usarlos luego:

así que lo que propongo es esto:

```
function obtenerEventos(id){
    return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
        $id = id;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' =>'CalendarioPlantillas', 'action' => 'eventosGerencia')); ?>", 
            headers : {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()
            },
            data:{
                idcentro:$id
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) 
            {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            },
            success:function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
                result = msg;
                res(msg);
                //callback(msg);
            },
            error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorMessage){
                //alert("Ha ocurrido un error inesperado intentelo de nuevo");
                console.log(errorMessage);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(xhr);
                rej(errorMessage);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Como vemos hemos encerrado el código de tu `AJAX` dentro de una `Promise`, a este resultado se le llama **promisificación**, ademas de cambiar tus return por `res` o `rej` que son los callback que recibe una promise para el manejo de retorno de `valor` o `error`, por lo cuál podrías verlo como `returns` personalizados dentro de la promise.

Ahora que ya **promisificamos** a `AJAX`, como he dicho antes **no podrás recuperar de manera directa el valor devuelto por la Promise**, si no que deberás usar `.then` y `.catch` donde desees recuperar o usar el valor de la Promise, tal como esto:

```
calendar.events.then(data =>{
  //Obtenemos la data traida por AJAX, solo aquí dentro tendras acceso a la data
  console.log(data);
}).catch(e)=>{
  //Obtenemos el error traido por AJAX (solo en caso de error).
}
```

Esa sería la forma de usar lo que habiamos hecho antes al `Promisificar` tu llamada a `AJAX`, aunque si quieres una forma mas corta y **estas dentro de una función asincrona**, puedes acortarlo a esto:

```
async function printEvents(){
   const events = await calendar.events;
   console.log(events);
}
```

**Recuerda, await no puede ser usado en el scope global y ademas solo esta disponible dentro de funciones o metodos que sean asincronos.**

Ademas cuando usamos `Promises` o `funciones asincronas` hay que olvidarse de el hecho de intentar asignar directamente valores a tus variables que provienen de código asincrono o funciones asincronas, puesto que hagas lo que hagas **no vas a poder**.

debes olvidarte de intentar "rescatar" estos valores de otra forma para asignarlo a variables externas para no tener que usar `await`, `.then` o `.catch`, puesto que simplemente esto es imposible para cosas que sean `asincronas`, asi funciona el mundo de lo `asincrono`.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muy elaborada. Solo cambiaría `scope` o `bloque` por `scope` o `contexto` y, aunque siempre es mejor esperar a tener las aclaraciones del AP para evitar _contestar basado en suposiciones_ ... +1

Comment: tengo una duda el calendar.events.then lo deberia llamar en la funcion obtenerEventos o fuera de ella

Answer (score -2):

Cuando la respuesta de la petición AJAX sea success, entonces en vez de retornar la variable, llama al metodo de calendar correspondiente.

Comment: Porfavor lee [answer].